Some input files use or override a deprecated API Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details
I'm building my react-native app for the first time using expo- EAS build and I run to alot of problem which after alot of search i realize it's not a javascript error but a native code error. How can I therefor solve this problem. Below is the output error
[stderr] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

[stderr] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

[stderr] Note: /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/android/src/javaPackage/java/com/reactnativecommunity/asyncstorage/AsyncStoragePackage.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.


[stderr] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

How do i recompile with -Xlint:deprecation  and also  -Xlint:unchecked



Have you considered doing what it says in the error message?

@user207421 thanks for your reply, but i don't know how to fix this as i interact only with javascript code i don't interact with native code, i don't even have adriod folder in my project so there's no way i could handle the error
